# Passing a different version number for jacoco maven plugin through jenkins goals and options

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I would like to pass a different version number of **jacoco maven plugin** in jenkins through goals and options for that project as the default version provided by the jenkins is not compatible. Can you please specify the command line that i can use in jenkins.

My current command line goals and options is :
**clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent -U install deploy -Dcatalina.home=$WORKSPACE -DskipITs**

btw i dont want to change my pom for each project as i have many projects with different poms which are using the default version number.

Regards
Sun

Comment: I fixed this by passing the version through command line as:clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent install

Comment: You should convert your comment to a full fledged answer, it deserves it.

Comment: Mithfindel; I fixed this by passing the version number in the goal and options of the project in jenkins as follows: clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128:prepare-agent -U install deploy -Dcatalina.home=$WORKSPACE -DskipITs. You can now compare both the commands and see the difference.